Does a New Tripod Need Lubrication?
I have a new tripod. In experimenting with it and learning to use it I keep thinking that it would work smoother if I put a little dry silicone lubricant on the threads.
For example
The collar leg lock threads

Center column lock and other threads.
Thread lubrication allows for more accurate and consistent tightening resulting in consistent clamping force.
I found articles on lubricating tripods after they get salt water on them or after they get dirty, but what about a new tripod?

I apologize for the confusion. My question is about lubricating a new tripod, not maintaining a tripod. My question was edited to have a maintenance title, I changed it to be more accurate.

It looks like you have a carbon fiber tripod with plastic leg locks. Whether it's a Gitzo, Really Right Stuff, Manfrotto, Benro, etc., the maintenance is pretty much all the same.
You don't need to lubricate the friction lock thread. In fact, any lubricant, including dry silicone grease, will likely attract and retain dust and grit, trapping it in the lock threads.
This RRS tripod breakdown and cleaning only recommends greasing the washers and bolts in the shoulder/apex joints with synthetic grease (w/ PTFE). Everything else (legs, leg locks, etc.) are just cleaned with mild soapy water and dried, reassembled without lubricants.
The locks in your tripod can be cleaned with a toothbrush and water. Just do it frequently enough to prevent buildup of dust, debris, salty water, etc., and you'll be fine.

Thank you for your answer. It is accurate for the changed title - related to maintenance on a tripod. My intent was to ask about lubrication on a new tripod. The article linked refers to using a "synthetic grease" on some parts. I have no experience with synthetic grease on a tripod but your concern about collecting dirt seems very valid.

I've experimented with a new tripod. Here's my experience.

For anodized threads dry silicone lubrication did not help with smoothness of operation or consistency of tightening over bare anodized threads.

For bare metal threads a very small amount of dry silicone lubrication did help with smoothness of operation.
My experiment left one leg of the tripod completely unlubricated so I can monitor what happens longer term.
